# jersey android volley Rest Web Service 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, android-volley

I'm new at developing RESTful Web Services. With a POST-Request I want to create an entity of type `Author`. I call the service via Android Volley from my Android smartphone and always get an HTTP Error `400 Bad Request`.
The JSON in the Request-Body is valid and the webservice works if I test it with Postman inside Chrome.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Author implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @XmlElement
    private String eMail;

    @XmlElement
    private String password;

    //GETTER & SETTER

}
```

Generated web service:

```
@Stateless
@Path("author")
public class AuthorFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Author> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Fremdenfuehrer_PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public AuthorFacadeREST() {
        super(Author.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void create(Author entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

}
```

Request with Android Volley:

```
RequestQueue mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .getRequestQueue();
String url = "http://192.168.5.101:8080/FremdenfuehrerWeb/webresources/author";
final Author registeredAuthor = new Author(eMail, password);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(registeredAuthor);

JSONObject jsonObject = null;
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
CustomJSONObjectRequest customJSONObjectRequest =
    new CustomJSONObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, 
        url, 
        jsonObject, 
        RegisterActivity.this, 
        RegisterActivity.this
    );

mQueue.add(customJSONObjectRequest);
```

The content-types are `application/json`.

Please Help! Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
I resolved the problem by changing from Android Volley to Retrofit Framework

Comment: Are you sure parentheses is correct around `json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1)`?

Comment: I'm sure this works. This row was even only to get sure that there are no additional characters which result an error. Even without this I geht a 400.

Comment: If you get a `400` on your smartphone, there has to be a sign of this also on the service side. Is there anything in your server's log?

Comment: The Server-Log shows absolutly no reaction to the requests.

Comment: From what you described (sorry if it is obvious to you), the request you are sending from the smartphone is different than the one from Postman. I would concentrate on finding out why: Print the `json`, compare it with the one you are sending with Postman. Print/debug info about the request before sending, check if everything is correct. Try to change the loglevels of your server, so that you get more info per incoming request. Unfortunately I've never worked with Volley, so I cannot give you specific help with that.

Comment: I already debuged the request, but in my opinion everything is right. Even if I copy the debug results into Postman it works. It couldn't be a problem with the URL too, because the GET-Method works.

Think I will try Retrofit and see if it does a POST